# Mount Multiple NFS Server Drives mount to single NFS client drive

Tags: 12.04, server, mount, nfs, storage

I've setUp the NFS Server on three machines each has 2 TB data storage size. So i've collectively 8 TB space on these three serves.

Now i've a situation that i've file of 8TB at NTFS client machine. I want to mount it transparently to these server.

`sudo mount ServerIP:/folder/already/setup/to/be/shared/home/username/folder/in/your/local`

**Can someone please tell me some mechanism that we can mount same directory of NFS client to multiple NFS Servers. SO that i can store the file 8TB in size.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Overview:**

Let’s say we have three disks but you wish to share with NFS clients and may be such situation when you want to mount multiple drives to single drive,..

**Solution:**
[Of course we can mount the disks on three separate mount points and export those](https://serverfault.com/questions/191299/can-we-mount-multiple-disks-as-one-directory). Or we can mount the three disks on three mount points inside the same directory and export the parent directory.

The problem with both solutions is you have to “balance” the data among the disks - and it will make navigating your TViX, WDTV or Popcorn more annoying. You could use RAID or LVM to handle all this for you. But. What if you already have data on the disks? What happens if one of the disks dies? With RAID0 or LVM your data is gone.

**Luckily we have the best of both worlds: mhddfs**

mhddfs is a FUSE plugin that combines data from several directories and present it in one directory. The only downside is that you do not know (or control) where a file is created.

Let’s say you combine `/dir1, /dir2 and /dir3 under /virtual`. Previously you had `/dir1/my_content`. This is now /virtual/my_content. If you write a file to /virtual/my_content it will not necessarily end up in `/dir1/my_content`. This also mean you can not predict what data is lost if you lose a disk.

The plugin is available in Ubuntu

```
$ sudo apt-get install mhddfs
```

Using it is pretty simple

```
$ sudo mkdir /export/hest
$ sudo mhddfs /dir1,dir2,dir3 /export/hest
[sudo] password for alj: 
mhddfs: directory '/dir1' added to list
mhddfs: directory '/dir2' added to list
mhddfs: directory '/dir3' added to list
mhddfs: mount to: /export/hest
mhddfs: move size limit 4294967296 bytes
```

The “move size limit” deserves an explanation:

if free space size threshold if a drive has the free space less than the    threshold specified then another drive will be chosen while creating a new file. If all the drives have free space less than the threshold specified then a drive containing most free space will be chosen.

```
/dir1;/dir2;/dir3
                      589G  329G  260G  56% /export/hest
```

To mount the combined directory during boot, at this to /etc/fstab:

```
mhddfs#/dir1,/dir2,/dir3 /export/hest fuse defaults,allow_other 0 0
```

we can export the combined directory using NFS or Samba. If you export the combined directory using NFS you need to add the fsid option in /etc/exports

```
/export/hest 192.168.1.0/24(fsid=2,ro,sync,crossmnt,no_subtree_check,insecure)
```

Comment: Anyone working on the same domain or problem.. welcome here for disucssion